# Convert compiled regex to string

Tags: regex, go

I don't have much experience in Go, but basically I want to print my regex on the screen after using it. I cant find anything on Google. This seems something rather easy to do but I have tried several things and nothing else worked.

```
var swagger_regex = regexp.MustCompile(`[0-9][.][0-9]`)
.... some code here ....
fmt.Println("Your '_.swagger' attribute does not match " + string(swagger_regex))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`regexp.Regexp`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp) type has a [`Regexp.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.String) method which does this exactly:

> String returns the source text used to compile the regular expression.

You don't even have to call it manually, as the `fmt` package checks and calls the `String()` method if the type of the passed value has it.

Example:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`[0-9][.][0-9]`)
fmt.Println("Regexp:", r)

// If you need the source text as a string:
s := r.String()
fmt.Println("Regexp:", s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/makN7JPQp7C)):

```
Regexp: [0-9][.][0-9]
Regexp: [0-9][.][0-9]
```

Comment: Oh my god I feel like the dumbest ever. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Glavić Yeah I was gonna do it but it was not allowing me due to time restriction.